# Bxslider set background color whole div to grey

Tags: html, css, bxslider

I want to set the background color for the whole of the slider to be `#efefef` but the css below doesn't do the trick there's a small margin of white around the div.

```
.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport { //remove , between both selectors
 //-----^----- added -
    background: #efefef;   
}
```

I've made a demo on jsfiddle of the slider on http://jsfiddle.net/vgJ9X/833/

EDIT:
I've edited it to include changes by dhaval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having a typo! and need to change selector for targetting viewport

It must be like following

```
    .bx-wrapper .bx-viewport { //remove , between both selectors
//-----^----- added -
        background: #efefef;   
    }
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vgJ9X/834/)

Comment: Thanks works there's a border of white how can I edit that also?